# How to use an Interface of external dll in c#

Tags: c#, dll, interop, dllimport

I need to use some methods that in an external dll, I have already done something like that, but this time that external dll is an Interface.

I do like this:

```
Assembly Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("fullpathofdll"); 
Type Type = Assembly.GetType("mytype"); 
dynamic Instance = Activator.CreateInstance(Type);
```

But I got this error: Cannot create an instance of an interface

I understand that's not possible instaciate an interface, but I don't know how to do this to work.

Someone can help?

Comment: Create an instance of a concrete class that implements that interface instead?

Comment: Inteface is just a code contract. You need to create instance of class that implements interface. And you of course can find many classes in dll that implements that interface. All those classes might have different implementations and you get different results of same method.

Comment: IF you don't have a concrete class, then you have no implementation, does the DLL not contain any types that implement the interface? If not then you just have a contract and no implementation, so you'll have write one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

An interface is supposed to be a "contract" for you to implement, not instantiate.
Your own implementation of the interface can then be instantiated via reflection the way you're doing above.

Comment: Sorry Keni, but I don't understand. Could you give me a sample of how to do this?